# SelectedValueChange() event firing during form load in a Windows Form application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, events

I'm having an issue where my SelectedValueChanged() event, on a ComboBox, is being triggered during the loading of my Windows Form application. Currently, I also have a Form_Load() event that is loading several ComboBoxes including this one, using OleDbDataAdapters/DataTables/Fill(), etc.

I'm assuming that because of my Form_Load() method, the SelectedValueChanged event is being triggered due to the data of the ComboBox being filled.

Why is this happening?

Comment: If you don't want the event to be raised during the initiation, why not subscribe to the event after all of your form initialization has taken place?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the form Load event before loading the items to the comboBox, unsubscribe for the event. After binding data subscribe to the event again.

```
Form_Load(..)
{
     _comboBoxName.SelectedValueChanged -= _comboBoxName_SelectedValueChanged;

    // Load data to the combo box... 

    _comboBoxName.SelectedValueChanged += _comboBoxName_SelectedValueChanged;
}
```

Comment: @James Durman: Great, don't forget the select the answer for your question.

Comment: @James: if this answer solved ur problem ,dont forget to mark it as the right one

Comment: @Grace thank you - I'm very new here. Just starting to get the hang of things.

Answer (score 3):

This event is probably being fired because of the data that is first being populated in the `ComboBox`. The best recommended fix would be to subscribe to events after the controls have been initialized.

Another simple fix is to assign a boolean flag when the Form has completely loaded. This flag could be used to ignore any calls to your event until the form is loaded (e.g. `FormLoaded = true`).

Answer (score 0):

```
rbtalldivision_CheckedChanged(sender, e);
rbtAllSitecodes_CheckedChanged(sender, e);
```

For callling  multiple events in windows application should work it